# How can i set Routing while creating admin panel

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

[image]
I want to  show only one component inside a white container that clicked but it is showing all  components . how can I create an admin panel with fine routing ???
Like other admin panel, i just want to show proper routing But in my case, both components are displaying

App.js, main file

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"
import Home from "./Components/Home/Home"
import CreateAccount from "./Components/Create-Account/CreateAccount"
import PostRequest from "./Components/Post-request/PostRequest"
import New from "./new"
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Home />
      <Route exact path="/" component={New} />
      <Switch >
        <Route exact path="/createAccount" component={CreateAccount} />
        <Route exact path="/postRequests" component={PostRequest} />
      </Switch>


    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App
```

And the Home page Component

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import "./home.css"
import PostRequest from "../Post-request/PostRequest"
import CreateAccount from "../Create-Account/CreateAccount"
import { SidebarData } from "./sideBarData"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
    },
    appBar: {
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
    },
    appBarShift: {
        width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
        marginLeft: drawerWidth,
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    hide: {
        display: 'none',
    },
    drawer: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        flexShrink: 0,
    },
    drawerPaper: {
        width: drawerWidth,
    },
    drawerHeader: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
        // necessary for content to be below app bar
        ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    },
    content: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing(3),
        transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
        marginLeft: -drawerWidth,
    },
    contentShift: {
        transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
        marginLeft: 0,
    },
}));

export default function PersistentDrawerLeft() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const theme = useTheme();
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleDrawerClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <AppBar
                position="fixed"
                className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
                    [classes.appBarShift]: open,
                })}
            >
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton
                        color="inherit"
                        aria-label="open drawer"
                        onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
                        edge="start"
                        className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
                    >
                        <MenuIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
                        Master Panel
                    </Typography>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <Drawer
                className={classes.drawer}
                variant="persistent"
                anchor="left"
                open={open}
                classes={{
                    paper: classes.drawerPaper,
                }}
            >
                <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
                    <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
                        {theme.direction === 'ltr' ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <ChevronRightIcon />}
                    </IconButton>
                </div>
                <Divider />
                <List>
                    <ul>
                        <h2>Admin</h2>
                        {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div>

                                    <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                                        <Link className="textClass" to={item.path}>
                                            <div className="listItem_Alignment container">
                                                <span>{item.icon}</span>
                                                <span className="titleLeftMargin">{item.title}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </Link>
                                    </li>

                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </List>
                <Divider />
            </Drawer>
            <main
                className={clsx(classes.content, {
                    [classes.contentShift]: open,
                })}
            >
                <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
                <CreateAccount />
                <PostRequest />
               
            </main>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested routing for your admin panel. You take reference of below link.

[Nested routing example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/route-config)